# Run jQuery ajax in custom intervals

Tags: jquery, ajax, intervals

I have a jQuery ajax function. On page load, it should **not** be executed. Then after 5 minutes, it should be executed, and then 5 minutes later, it gets executed again and so on...

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data : {action: "check_noti_log"},
    context: this,
    success:function(data){
        // return new logs (data)
        jQuery('#ajax_new_logs').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Consider `setInverval()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval`. The first parameter is the function you want to be executed and the second one defines the intervals (in milliseconds) on how often to execute the code. In your case `5 minutes = 300 seconds` which is `300*1000 milliseconds`.

```
setInterval(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data : {action: "check_noti_log"},
    context: this,
    success:function(data){
        // return new logs (data)
        jQuery('#ajax_new_logs').html(data);
    }
  });
}, 300000);
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to do that is set a timeout for five minutes, then call your function with itself again after your code executes. Let me know if that code breaks, I can't test it in my environment.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
function periodicCallAJAX(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      jQuery.ajax({
         url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
         data : {action: "check_noti_log"},
         context: this,
         success:function(data){
            // return new logs (data)
            jQuery('#ajax_new_logs').html(data);
         }
     });
     periodicCallAJAX();
    },300000);
    }
   });
```